# Can I restart MySQL engine when WordPress website is live?

Tags: mysql, vps

I'm dealing with resources processes problems in MySQL engine installed on an Ubuntu server, which hosts a WordPress website.

So, I want to try restarting the service, will using the `service mysql restart` command will do graceful restart?

Using the restart command accomplish the same as restarting the Ubuntu server?

If not, which is the best way to gracefully restart mysql on an Ubuntu server hosting a WordPress website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `service mysql restart` (or `systemctl restart mysql` on more recent versions of Linux) will carry out a graceful shutdown and restart of mysql.

Comment: Thank you. But just to be sure, can I run this command while the site is live? I mean, I won't be trying to save a post and I'm using cache plugin.

Comment: You can do it, and between mysqld being shut down and coming back up, there will be some seconds during which it will not be accepting connections from your application. All existing connections will be reset. Anything that happens during that time will result in an error.